# Highlight selected points in a plot

Tags: plotting, color

I need to change color to selected points dynamically in my plot.

```
clicks = {}; insert = 0;
Column[{
   ListPlot[Button[Tooltip@#, If[insert < 5 && ! MemberQ[clicks, #],
      AppendTo[clicks, #]; insert++;]] & /@ N@data, ImageSize -> 300], "\n\t",
    Row[{"clicks = ", Dynamic[clicks // TableForm]}],   
    Row[{Button["Del L1", If[Length[clicks] >= 1, insert--; clicks = Delete[clicks, 1]]]}]}
]
```

[image: plot]

I managed how to get x/y clicked, but not how to highlight it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
clicks = {}; insert = 0;
data = RandomReal[100, {50, 2}];
```

You can add the points in `clicks` using `Epilog`:

```
Column[{ListPlot[Button[Tooltip@#, 
        If[insert < 5 && ! MemberQ[clicks, #], AppendTo[clicks, #]; 
         insert++;]] & /@ N@data, ImageSize -> 400, 
   Epilog -> Dynamic[{ Directive[Opacity[.7, Red], PointSize[Large]], Point@clicks}]], 
   "\n\t",  Row[{"clicks = ", Dynamic[clicks // TableForm]}], 
   Row[{Button["Del L1", If[Length[clicks] >= 1, insert--; 
      clicks = Delete[clicks, 1]]]}]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can `Style` the points in `clicks` and add them to the list of points to be plotted:

```
Dynamic@Column[{ListPlot[Join @@ 
   {Style[#, Directive[Opacity[.5], Orange, Magnification -> 2]] & /@ clicks, 
    Button[Tooltip[#], If[insert < 5 && ! MemberQ[clicks, #], AppendTo[clicks, #]; 
            insert++;]] & /@ N@data}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]], "\n\t", 
   Row[{"clicks = ", Dynamic[clicks // TableForm]}], 
   Row[{Button["Del L1", If[Length[clicks] >= 1, insert--; 
       clicks = Delete[clicks, 1]]]}]}]
```

[image]